# Magento 2 set email template for customer_account_information_change_email_template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, email-templates, magento-2.1.7

I've been building on a Magento 2.1.7 store for a while now and changed all Magento email templates using the built-in editor, however, I can't seem to find the config value for which template to use when a customer changes its email address, I've looked around in every store config page possible.

All I can see is the value being created in vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/config.xml:30

Does anybody know how to set this template in the store configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for change password template for load template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a bug in Magento 2.1.7, it has been fixed in Magento 2.1.8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set change password template, see below details

```
Admin >> Marketing >> Email Templates >> Add New Template >> Load default template >> Template
```

Select "**Change Email**"

"Change Email" template is use for customer change password.

Comment: Sorry, I asked for the wrong template, I've updated my question.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: This issue was a bug in Magento 2.1.7, it has been fixed in Magento 2.1.8, thank you for your answer anyways!